# Killing containers in an isolated minon

Tags: kubernetes

What is the strategy of kubelet managing containers within the machine if the connection with the master is broken due to some network issue? Is it possible to configure kubelet to kill all containers in such a situation?

Comment: if a minion is isolated, pods will be killed and rescheduled on healthy nodes as long as the resource are available. it takes a few minutes for this to happen though. To make sure things run as they should, you may want to setup liveness and readiness probes.

Comment: If the connection with the master is broken, the containers will keep running. The kubelet assumes here it is the true world. If you want your containers to be killed, you might want to look at the health service.

Comment: What is the health service? Is it a standard service to check system health?

Answer (score 0):

Nodes in Kubernetes checkin with the master on regular intervals. If they fail to check in AND the master is still up then the pod eviction timout flag comes into play.

It basically waits this time before the pods are rescheduled elsewhere in the cluster. This is common to wait if the machine is just rebooting or something similar.

The flag is in the controller manager: `--pod-eviction-timeout=5m0s: The grace period for deleting pods on failed nodes.`

The second scenario is when the master goes down (or more specifically the controller-manager). If it stops responding then the cluster will still function as-is without interuption.